# Determine Object Type in ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, .net, xml, expandoobject

I have derived a class which will take an XML file and generate ExpandoObject dynamically for the XML being passed in utilizing Lists of ExpandoObjects and recursion.

Passing this back to be processed to retrieve data works, but the XML that I am retrieving from a legacy system is inconsistent. I can either get back a single node as such

```
<test>
 <insured>
  <a>BLAH BLAH BLAH</a>
  <b>BLAH BLAH BLAH</b>
  <c>BLAH BLAH BLAH</c>
 </insured>
</test>
```

or

```
<test>
 <insured>
  <a>BLAH BLAH BLAH</a>
  <b>BLAH BLAH BLAH</b>
  <c>BLAH BLAH BLAH</c>
 </insured>
 <insured>
  <a>BLAH BLAH BLAH</a>
  <b>BLAH BLAH BLAH</b>
  <c>BLAH BLAH BLAH</c>
 </insured>
 <insured>
  <a>BLAH BLAH BLAH</a>
  <b>BLAH BLAH BLAH</b>
  <c>BLAH BLAH BLAH</c>
 </insured>
</test>
```

So for the key 'insured' I am either getting an `ExpandoObject` or `List<ExpandoObject>`. I am trying to determine the simplest solution to determine the type being returned.

Ideally just something like `x.insured.OfType<List<ExpandoObject>>()` to return a bool or something of that nature.

Cheers

Comment: Why don't you make it *always* give you back a `List<ExpandoObject>` - just a single-valued list if there's only one entry?

Comment: In trying to make this code as re-usable as possible and dynamic, I feel it would complicate things for where this does not occur. The sample XML I gave above does not reflect the complicated nature of the real source.

Comment: That's the problem with not giving representative examples :) But I think that presenting a *simple* model where referring to a subelement name always gets a *sequence* of matches is the most consistent approach.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jon. Thinking about this further and talking with a co-worker I think this will be the easiest solution, just will need to bear in mind whilst implementing. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you may have resolve this with Jon Skeet's help, but in case you're wondering, you can use the `is` operator for this:

```
if(x.insured is List<ExpandoObject>) {
    foreach(dynamic item in x.insured) {
        DoSomething(item);
    }
} else {
    DoSomething(x.insured);
}
```

Comment: Excellent, that was really the answer I was looking for. I will weigh my two options. Cheers.